# Clip-path (mask) CSS style on image slider (cross browser)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cross-browser, clip-path

I've been trying to mask a jQuery image slider.
The slider contains the following structure:

```
<div class="flexslider">
<ul class="slides">
    <li style="background-image: url('slides/1.jpg');"></li>
    <li style="background-image: url('slides/2.jpg');"></li>
    <li style="background-image: url('slides/3.jpg');"></li>
    <li style="background-image: url('slides/4.JPG');"></li>
    <li style="background-image: url('slides/5.jpg');"></li>
    <li style="background-image: url('slides/6.jpg');"></li>
    <li style="background-image: url('slides/7.jpg');"></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

In this structure I would like to apply the clip-path property to the flexslider div.
In Chrome this works fine by adding the -webkit- prefix to the property but Firefox and IE don't seem to support the normal clip-path property.

I've been looking online for a cross browser solution but I am not able to find one.
I saw Firefox only supports url values as the clip-path property but IE doesn't support it at all.

This is the idea:

[image]

The red part is the image slider.

Does someone know a cross browser solution for this?

Thanks!